# mysql: join two tables, and after split a column of the result table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, left-join

i have a principal table of articles:

```
id | article_title  | idSeries | idJournal
1  | title1         |    1     |
2  | title2         |    1     |    2
```

and a table with titles of series and journal of an article

```
id| publication_title | Type
1 |    title_serie1   | serie
2 |  title_journal1   | journal
```

in the first case, i have a article that has only a serie (the firts row in second table); in the second case, i have a article that has a serie and a journal (the two rows in the second table).
Is it possible with a join of these two tables create a query that split "publication_title" in two columns? (one for serie and one for journal?)

For example:

```
select article_title, GROUP_CONCAT(publication_title)
from articles
left join table2 on articles.idSeries = table2.id or articles.idJournal = table2.id
where articles.id = 2
```

the result of this query could be something like:

```
id  |   article_title  |   publication_title
2   |    title2        | title_serie1title_journal1
```

is there a way to split "publication_title" and get a field for "title_serie1" and another field for "title_journal1"? Or is it impossible in this case And i have to change the tables? I want different field because after i have to check with PHP if exixst a serie or a journal for one book.

Result that i want:

```
id  |   article_title  |   publication_title(serie) | publication_title(journal)
2   |    title2        |      title_serie1          |      title_journal1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `left join` twice:

```
select a.article_title, ts.publication_title serie_title, tj.publication_title journal_title
from articles a
left join table2 ts on ts.id = a.idSeries and ts.type = 'serie'
left join table2 tj on tj.id = a.idJournal and tj.tpe = 'journal'
where a.id = 2
```

Note that your data model has some kind of redondancy. The `article` has two different columns for series and journals, but this information is repeated in column `type` of `table2`: either one, or the other is sufficient.

Comment: That's just what I wanted! Thanke you!